# Clean deleted R. Cant run any of my codeI

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I did clean project and now i cannot run any of my code.  Any files that has to do with R, just says cannot be resolved as a field.  I've looked at so many other stackoverflow posts with similar problems but none seems to actually help.  Help please!!

I have about 15 classes but here is an example

```
package com.Class;


import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class NewAccount extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Clean, if that does not work, Exit eclipse and reload.  You should have code completion; do you?

Comment: The code works.  The only erros are when my programs are looking for the layouts but cannot find the R.java

Comment: I've tried putting the code into a new project 3 times but the problem is following the code.  I dont understand

Comment: If the problem is following the code, you really should thoroughly parse through your source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If R.java is not being generated, chances are there are some other errors in your code than the ones referring to the R file. Find these errors, solve them, and then R will be regenerated.

Comment: Make sure the Problems view is open; it will report other problems in the project, such as invalid XML, buil path problems, Java compilation errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the R file?

import com.example.myapp.R;

This may be useful too: [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: Try adding a new Android layout XML file from Eclipse? Specifically pick "Android XML file" from the eclipse menu.